# Android closest road from shapefile and road speed attribute from shapefile

Tags: android, arcgis, shapefile

While I am driving in the car, I need to compare speed from gps and speed of the road where I am driving.

All roads and their speed I have defined inside shapefile (shp, shx, prj, dbf)

Shapefile contains 45000 segments, and it size is 50MB, which is probably reason why I should use Server side for this application.

I know how to get my current latitude,longitude and speed from gps, but I don't know how to find closest road from shapefile and take speed atrribute from it.

Every idea I will appreciate.

Comment: This would probably be better posted over on [GIS.SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com). ;)

Comment: I solved this problem with Spatialite for Android: https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=splite-android